# Flutter: How to make a more animated button with depth in it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know the buttons in flutter like floating action button, raised button ,etc they have this material ripple effect but I wanted something with more animation in it like depth like it's being pushed down

an exmple below:

[image: Button Image]

Comment: Flutter uses material design, where button elevation (z-index) is defined by shadow. What button you are showing is a different thing. But you can easily make this custom button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to this >Medium post by Mariano Zorrilla

https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-create-an-animated-fancy-button-for-flutter-games-and-apps-3da7b81c2c12"

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful, I appreciated